# How to wait for any single child process to terminate, on a bash without wait -n?

Tags: bash, wait, child-process

I basically need to figure a replacement for `wait -n` that I may use in older versions of `bash` (e.g., `bash` 4.2 as included in CentOS 7) to wait for the termination of *any* child process (not *all*). Am I out of luck? Trapping `SIGCHLD` won't work in my scenario.

Comment: I think you're out of luck. The `-n` option was added because there wasn't a way to do it before.

Comment: If you control how the child processes are started, you could start each as `(command && touch $$)` and then use `inotifywait` or a loop with intermediate sleeps to wait for one of the files to appear.

Comment: I do control. That sounds interesting. What about the case when `commands` exits abnormaly—will `||` instead of `&&` suffice?

Comment: If you know how many backgrounded processes you've launched then you could compare that number against the result of `pgrep -c -P $$` which will tell you how many are still running.

Comment: @Miguel Use `(command; touch ...)` if you are indifferent to whether `command` succeeds or not. `$$` isn't appropriate, because it's always the process ID of the parent shell, not the subshell. `(command & pid=$!; wait; touch $pid)` might be more appropriate. The risk that your machine will spawn so many processes quickly enough that `pid` is not necessarily unique within your group of processes is vanishingly small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a FIFO to send notifications on exit:

```
mkfifo notify_fd
exec 3<>notify_fd
count=0

background() { { "$@"; echo "${BASHPID} $?" >&3; } & (( ++count )); }

background sleep 3
background sleep 4
background sleep 5

while read pid status <&3; do
  echo "One exited, with PID $pid and status $status"
  (( --count == 0 )) && break
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the PID, the most obvious solution would be:

```
while ps $pid > /dev/null ; do
    sleep 1
done
```

That is not quite the same as waiting for the signals, but functionally it would do the same.

Comment: The OP has many PIDs, not just one; they wish to wait for *any one of the set*. (And frankly, `ps $pid` is *much* less efficient than `kill -0 "$pid"` as a way to check if a single PID is active).